# Conditional compilation turned off warning when mixing razor and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The following snippet triggers a "Conditional compilation turned off" warning in one of my views. Do you have an idea on how to fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        @RenderSection("JQueryDocumentReady",false)
    });
</script>
```

I tried to insert a semicolon at the end of the render section statement but it didn't help.

Thank you.

Comment: Note for others: despite the errors displayed in the code, the razor code is still executed/compiled correctly.  So the compiler is able to handle razor/JS, it's just the intellisense or whatever component displays the as-you-type squiggles that has a problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NOTE: Answer accepted because of alternative suggestion to the question, not solution given for the problem in title.

I'm not 100% sure what Conditional Compilation has to do with being in a `<script>` block, but I did find that wrapping the statements in parenthesis fixed the problem.

```
@(RenderSection("JQueryDocumentReady"))
```

I do think this method has a bit of code smell though.  It's not a problem to just have a script section and assign things to document ready on each page.  It really isn't going to save you much work, and it will force you to put javascript on views outside of script tags the way you have chosen to do it.

Comment: This introduces another warning: *Invalid character* on the opening parenthesis. I think this is a lost cause. We just have to wait for better Razor integration in vNext.

Comment: @NickLarsen Agree on the javascript outside of script tags part. Thank you for your answer and advice.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I see it now, just doesn't highlight it for me in the editor.

Comment: @NickLarsen, yeah, Razor integration in Visual Studio is buggy. We just have to be a little more patient. Not that I care about it but for people that have activated Razor compilation and wait for ages when they press F5.

Comment: @Darin Indeed, it introduces an invalid char warning :( Donno what is worse, the old or the new warning...

Comment: @Chaker Nakhli, the old as it makes you type less characters (-2 parenthesis :-))

Comment: I'm going to leave my code as it is then :-). I'll accept the answer though since I didn't see the js outside of the script tag problem. Thank you both NickLarsen and @Darin Dimitrov

Answer (score 0):

you can try

`$(document).ready(function () {
        '@RenderSection("JQueryDocumentReady",false)';
    });`